# Can't run APP - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-android

```
react-native: 0.46.4
```

I'm getting this error's only on android:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules Process: br.com.MYPACKAGE, PID: 2964 com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: No dimension set for key window
```

I've searched that it happens using Router Flux, but i don't use it.

Any help?

Comment: can you add a snippet from your code please? Seems like you are trying to get dimension of the window but I assume you have something wrong

Comment: Is this happens on fresh installation of RN? Or you already done some works on it?